# BitBake override style removal with variable expansion

Tags: bitbake, openembedded

I face a problem that I tried to use the BitBake override style removal with variable expansion.

I have a `foo.bb` and set `FOO_PACKAGES = "${PN}_dummy"`
And I use a `foo.bbappend` to remove it by `FOO_PACKAGES_remove = "${PN}_dummy"`

This doesn't work.

However, `FOO_PACKAGES_remove = "foo_dummy"` works fine.

Furthermore I tried other variable names besides `PN`, e.g.

```
FOO_PACKAGES = "foo_dummy"
FOONAME = "foo"
FOO_PACKAGES_remove = "${FOONAME}_dummy"
```

This doesn't work either.

So maybe there is some issue with variable expansion in the override style removal?

I use BitBake 1.22 and am sorry I cannot test the master branch on my working environment.

```
BitBake Build Tool Core version 1.22.0, bitbake version 1.22.0
```

Does somebody have some idea about the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need this patch:

http://git.openembedded.org/bitbake/commit/lib/bb/data_smart.py?h=1.24&id=72a1ca4a104ccab73d6abcbd44db9c2636a58572

which is in bitbake 1.24 and above.